# missing EOF from HTTP stream without Transfer-Encoding chunked

Tags: netty

I am streaming content over HTTP with Netty 4.  The content is generated dynamically, so there is no way to know the content length ahead of time.  My existing non-netty code writes to an `OutputStream`, so I wrote a simple wrapper around an `OutputStream` that takes the writes and puts them in a `ByteBuf`, and when that's full, it writes it as the payload of `DefaultHttpContent`.  Prior to any writes to the `OutputStream`, I send a non-full `HttpResponse` w/ an `OK` status code.

When the close is called on the stream, i send whatever is in the local ByteBuf that has not been sent, and then `LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT`.

What I see with wget is that it gets all the bytes, but then sits and waits for the end of the stream.  If I put the Transfer-Encoding: Chunked header in the initial response, things work perfectly.

I can see some differences in the handling of the LastHttpContent message in `HttpObjectEncoder` which is what clued me in about trying the chunked transfer header.  What I'm unclear about is what the difference is and why the EOF seems to not be sent w/o the header, even though all the bytes are sent *and* I'm sending `LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT`

**EDIT:**

I am able to reproduce this behavior via a simple modification to `HttpStaticFileServerHandler` in the Netty 4 examples.  I am using [this class](https://gist.github.com/mhgrove/6464352) to send the file back to the client, [this](https://gist.github.com/mhgrove/6464409) (requires Guava) is my modified `channelRead0` method from `HttpStaticFileServerHandler` which instead of setting the content length & writing the file directly to the channel, it copies the File to the channel via `ByteBuffHttpOutputStream` which sends 1 MB chunks of output via `DefaultHttpContent` and on `close` sends a `LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT`.  If I remove the setting of the `Transfer-Encoding` header: (`response.headers().set(Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, Values.CHUNKED)`) then using wget to grab the file never completes.  afaict, I'm sending the stream correctly, and it *looks* like `HttpObjectEncoder` should be handling the `LastHttpContent` correctly, but yet, no EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was just fixed in master and will be part of 4.0.9.Final

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/1787

Comment: I think you need to close the channel after the LastHttpContent was written as you no set any content-length.

Comment: I suspect that will work, but doesn't that completely defeat the client asking for a keep-alive connection?

Comment: Unless you specify the Content-Length and do not use chunked encoding, the only way to know the end of the content is the end of the connection.

Comment: So keep-alive and streaming content back to a client are mutually exclusive?